# code mirror shows PHP code in the editor?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using `code mirror` in one of my projects to allow users edit a page live using a `textarea`.

However, the page that I am letting the users to edit is a `.php` file.

when I open the page with code mirror or, `it will display the PHP code` as well as the `HTML and javascript, CSS` etc!

I thought that the code mirror or any other code editors would not be able to show the PHP code as the PHP is server side!

is there any way to just display the HTML/javascript/CSS in the textarea in the editor?

here is the current code:

```
<?php

$fn = "index.php";



if (isset($_POST['content']))

{

    $content = stripslashes($_POST['content']);

    $fp = fopen($fn,"w") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");

    fputs($fp,$content);

    fclose($fp) or die ("Error closing file!");

}

?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/codemirror.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/theme/night.css">
<script src="lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="lib/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
<script src="lib/addon/display/fullscreen.js"></script>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">

    <textarea id="code"  style="width:450px;"  rows="25" cols="50" name="content"><?php readfile($fn); ?></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Save"> 

</form>

  <script>
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
      lineNumbers: true,
      theme: "night",
      extraKeys: {
        "F11": function(cm) {
          cm.setOption("fullScreen", !cm.getOption("fullScreen"));
        },
        "Esc": function(cm) {
          if (cm.getOption("fullScreen")) cm.setOption("fullScreen", false);
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Browsers parse any text within `textarea` as characters. It doesn't matter, if the text forms some php, or whatever code.

Comment: @Teemu, it doesn't matter what I use (input field) it still shows the PHP code!

Comment: (a) cant understand why you'd open the file in write mode. (b) How do you propose the library would be able to cope with all possible combinations of php/html/css/javascript found in a file, other than displaying it all? Consider the following: You've got a page that needs some changes made to the html, problem is some of that html is generated by php. So what then? Do you exclude some content, send the remaining, before then receiving a response and try to re-merge the excluded content? Seems unreasonable to expect to be able edit anything but the entire contents of the file to me.

Comment: @enhzflep, Consider the following:, sorry but i don't see any following other than some more questions! am I missing something in your reply?

Comment: @user3454730 - Consider the following `"You've got a page that needs some changes made to the html, problem is some of that html is generated by php"`

Comment: @enhzflep, so what are my options do you think?

Comment: is it safe to let the users view the PHP code?

Comment: Safe? Depends on the site and the audience. An intranet project would probably be okay - I wouldn't trust it in the hands of the public, they'd nuke you in just hours. Options? * you could use file_get_contents with the url of the php file, rather than fopen with a local-path ***that*** would return just php generated html/css/javascript - though you couldn't write these changes back to the original file - you'd lose the dynamic behaviour. * You could put html/css sections of the page in separate files, allowing just those to be edited. Otherwise, bit hard to say without more background info.

Comment: @enhzflep, Thanks mate... I agree. I would not trust it in the hands of public. I will let the users to edit the CSS files only. safer and no hassle dealing with malicious users in the future.